Дробная часть SQL
Делаю выборку из таблицы суммы поступлений (изначально столбец в формате float4). Если группирую по месяц, то все корректно отображается (суммы с дробной частью). Если же пытаюсь просто вывести значение без группировки, то выдается число с округлением до целого. Суммирую через SUM(). Пробовал через CAST менять принудительно на float, но не помогает.
select extract(month from pay_date) as month, sum(pay_summ) from kamtent.sales
where pay_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-12-31'
group by month
order by month




month
sum(pay_summ)




1
2406129.0


2
4156632.0


3
2371564.5


4
2435626.0



select sum(pay_summ) from kamtent.sales
where pay_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-12-31'




sum(pay_summ)




11369952




SQL запросы в студию + выводимый результат

select extract(month from pay_date) as month, sum(pay_summ) from kamtent.sales
where pay_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-12-31'
group by month
order by month
1 2406129.0
2 4156632.0
3 2371564.5
4 2435626.0

select sum(pay_summ) from kamtent.sales
where pay_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-12-31'
11369952

ставлю на то, что float в этой задаче вовсе не может использоваться. Ну да, "pay", "sales". Нельзя тут float принципиально по определению этого формата.

пробовал в dbeaver выбирать формат money, но там вообще становятся цифры с вопросительными знаками в конце

numeric вообще добавляет дробную часть там, где её не должно быть и убирает там, где она должна появиться

Попробуйте в sum(pay_summ) сразу pay_summ кастовать в нормальный numeric, а потом уже суммировать. А вообще float4 для денег - это очень жёстко, интересно прям, кто же до такого догадался ))

SELECT SUM(CAST(pay_summ AS numeric(10,2))) from kamtent.sales
where pay_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-12-31' результат не изменился

перевёл сначала в money (суммы корректно стали рассчитываться, но появился ? в конце), затем перевёл в numeric и всё стало ок, вроде))

Вы видите не число, а то, что получается после перевода его сначала (1) в десятичную систему счисления, а затем (2) в строковое представление, с усечением точности, так как десятичное представление почти всегда является бесконечной дробью.
Первое преобразование прописано в стандарте IEEE 754, второе спрятано где-то внутри программы, в которой вы смотрите на результат.
По стандарту Float4 обеспечивает только 7 точных знаков, 8-й как повезёт, дальше чаще всего будет мусор.
В ваших примерах я вижу, что всё время выводится именно 8 значащих цифр (2406129.0 — 7 до разделителя, и 1 после; 11369952 — все восемь до).
Могу предположить, что представление Float4 как 8 десятичных знаков задано именно средой выполнения.

Пробовал через CAST менять принудительно на float, но не помогает.

Не вижу в документации по postgresql типа float, могу предположить, что этот псевдоним для float4. Попробуйте выполнить cast в float8.
А вообще для денег лучше использовать типы с фиксированной точностью, например, numeric(10,2)

Судя по документации, в Postrgesql вообще всё печально для типа float4:

PostgreSQL воспринимает запись от float(1) до float(24) как выбор типа real

И далее:

real - 4 байта - вещественное число с переменной точностью - точность в пределах 6 десятичных цифр

Только 6 десятичных цифр гарантировано, что будут точно переданы, а у вас до запятой уже 7 цифр! Что уж тут беспокоиться про цифры после запятой. Я бы проверил, что сумма хотя бы до запятой одинаково посчиталась в обоих случаях.
В общем, используйте более точные типы данных для денег:

double precision - 8 байт - вещественное число с переменной точностью - точность в пределах 15 десятичных цифр


numeric - переменный - вещественное число с указанной точностью - до 131072 цифр до десятичной точки и до 16383 — после

Вообще принято для денег использовать decimal/numeric, чтобы гарантированно не потерять ни копейки при расчётах.

Что-то по ссылке перевод кривой. Там же в английской версии написано "with a precision of at least 6 decimal digits", то есть с точностью не менее 6 знаков.

@ГерманБорисов Я что-то не пойму в чём разница. 6 цифр, 6 знаков - и? Это же не "после запятой", это вообще. "digits" - это "цифры", а не "знаки", если что.

По-русски написано "в пределах шести", то есть не больше, а по-английски — "не меньше шести"

@ГерманБорисов Спасибо, я теперь понял. Хотя смысловая разница не велика. 6 цифр будут гарантированно переданы правильно, а дальше - как кости лягут. Что так, что так.

Меня это смутило, потому что стандарт гарантирует "не меньше семи".

@ГерманБорисов Возможно, это какие-то особенности внутренней реализации типа real в постгрессе. Это только исходники копать, чтобы понять, в чём прикол. Может там биты какие-то на что-то ещё зарезервированы, не знаю.

при попытке в Dbeaver поменять на money выдает SQL Error [42846]: ОШИБКА: привести тип real к money нельзя

Тогда видимо только создать новый столбец такого типа, скопировать туда данные. Старый столбец удалить. Новый переименовать. И не забыть туда индексы добавить, если там были.

перевёл сначала в money (суммы корректно стали рассчитываться, но появился ? в конце), затем перевёл в numeric и всё стало ок, вроде))
